# Automatic splitting of displayed equations using only commands in the preamble

Tags: equations, preamble, split

I have a LaTeX project with one main file, and several subfiles corresponding to chapters of my textbook. One of my students is vision impaired making it necessary for me to create a special version of my book with extra-large fonts throughout.

The aim is to be able to have two main files, one for the standard version and another for the special, and only one version of each subfile so I don't have to make each change twice. So far I have managed to find ways to deal with all problems following from this requirement except for one:

Some displayed equations are too long to fit on one line of the large-font-version of my book. I would like those to be automatically split into two (or more) lines to avoid treating each such case separately (tedious) and producing two versions of each subfile (making a mess). The priority is not to make them look good, just legible.

Is there any way to achieve automatic splits of displayed equations by modifying the main file?

Comment: not easily.  Also it depends how the original is marked up, `equation`, `align`, ... ? Are you providing the book on paper, not electronically?

Comment: you can always do this by hand something like `\ifLargeFont \begin{align}a&=b\\+c\end{align} \else \begin{equation}a=b+c\end{equation}\fi`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Both on paper and electronically. In any case, it must be ready for print (both versions). The \ifLargeFont idea is good and thanks for it, but it means some extra work and it will clutter the files. I was hoping for some sort of hack that would spare me the extra typing (and teach me something new).

Comment: but for an `align` which already has multiple lines and alignment points specified it would be very hard to come up with an automatic solution to break and re-align at a different place.  One thing you could do, if the equation is too wide is set it rotated by 90 degress which might look odd or might work, depending....

Comment: It's already set to landscape, so rotating wouldn't help. I know about the problem with align; it's a good point and it makes my wish hard to use in a general setting, but in the case of this book there would be so few problematic occurrences that I'd be alright with that. (Or perhaps use the \ifLargeFont approach for just those cases.)

Comment: well for `equation`  you can (automatically) replace it by `\begin{center}$\displaystyle ...$\end{equation}` which then allows linebreaking is that enough of an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `equation` you can in the large print version define it as inline `\displaystyle`.
Then it has a chance of line breaking at infix operators and relations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewenvironment{equation*}
   {\begin{center}$\displaystyle}{$\end{center}}

\renewenvironment{equation}
   {\begin{center}\refstepcounter{equation}$\displaystyle}{$\quad(\theequation)\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{equation}
  1+2+3+4+6+7=7+6+5 4+4+2+1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't handle `align` and even with equation a large `\frac` or `\left..\right` pair will still prevent breaking.  It's possible to go further and disable `\left` and `\right` and defien `\frac` to be an inline fraction such as `(#1)/(#2)` so that linebreaking is possible but soing these kind of breaks automatically at arbitrary points may not make the expressions really readable.

Comment: This solution is fine for the starred version of equation environment, but how about hyperlinks to equations?
`\begin{equation}\label{E:foo}
...
\end{equation}
\eqref{E:foo}` does not work... Is there a way to make it work in the usual way without changing the syntax (and thus without making it necessary to change the subfile)?

Comment: @MrMRm slightly more coherent version posted

Comment: I think an ideal solution should leave the equations as in the original. Magnify with the screen reader (all can do). For printing small driver ala graphics? Otherwise, redefine as you did (put in box and scale?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, now it works including the hyperlinks. However, the number positioning is not great. Do you think the following modification is alright (seems to be working)?
`\renewenvironment{equation}
   {\bigskip\newline\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}\begin{center}\refstepcounter{equation}$\displaystyle}
   {$\end{center}\end{minipage}\hfill(\theequation)\bigskip}`

I am worried about the "hardcoded" 0.9\textwidth. In any case, many thanks for your help!

Comment: @YiannisLazarides that was my initial thought too which is why ai sked if paper version was necessary, but I'm not sure what the print version driver would do that you have in mind?

Comment: @MrMRm I wondered about using  a minipage for equation number yes that's reasonable

Comment: My student needs to print it out with text size close to 40pt. Of course she can use a magnifying tool on her computer, but reading from the screen makes her eyes even more tired than they already are. The way I achieve this font size is to use extbook documentclass with 17pt and A6 paper (geometry); she then prints it enlarged to A4.

Comment: The "driver" would just insert the pdf special to scale (similar to TeX original magstep).

Comment: @MrMRm  I understand. My suggestion is not to use a "tool"  for the reader; acrobat can do it naturally.